# How do I get sum of likes alongside other values in another table

Tags: laravel, left-join

I have two tables like this

**video** table :

```
vid_id    title
 1         differentation
 2         antonyms
 3         calculas
```

**views_like** table :

```
id   vid_id   views   likes
 1     2       1        1
 2     2       1        1
 3     2       1        1
 4     1       1        1
 5     1       1        1
```

How do I get the sum of the likes of each video alongside the title in laravel. here is my code.

```
  $rec_videos = Videos::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->where('publish', 1)
       ->leftJoin('views_likes', 'videos.vid_id', '=', 'views_likes.vid_id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by` and `count` together.

```
$rec_videos = Videos::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->where('publish', 1)
       ->leftJoin('views_likes', 'videos.vid_id', '=', 'views_likes.vid_id')
       ->select('videos.id as id', 'videos.title as title', DB::raw("count(views_likes.vid_id) as count"))
       ->groupby('videos.id')
        ->get();
```